# Debugging user event in a Java GUI Application

Tags: java, swing, jakarta-ee

I am using a Java Project that gives an user interface for doing some user events. It is not being executed as Runnable thread in main() as in most Swing/Gui applications. Rather it has several class and form files in the source code and is run from command line using another Java program. 
But when I am trying to read a certain file by clicking on some input button, the system fails to read the file. The system writes the custom error message into a file named log.txt saved within the project folder. 
I have tried 
1. Setting breakpoints (the application does not stop at breakpoint)
2. Doing console prints i.e. System.out.println (there is no print on console)

So both the ways of debugging has failed. I am using Eclipse 3.5.2 SDK (Galileo). How can I debug the user events on my applicattion?

The outline of the source class DataImportPanel in project DDMT is listed below. It is giving an exception in the method DataImportPanel.openHeteroFile(File).

```
DDMT.core.DataImportPanel 
... 
DDMT.core.DataImportPanel.heteroDistributionModel 
...  
DDMT.core.DataImportPanel.initComponents() 
DDMT.core.DataImportPanel.initComponents().new ActionListener() {...} 
...
DDMT.core.DataImportPanel.initComponents().new MouseAdapter() {...} 
DDMT.core.DataImportPanel.initComponents().new ActionListener() {...} 
DDMT.core.DataImportPanel.jButton2ActionPerformed(ActionEvent) 
... 
DDMT.core.DataImportPanel.jButton3ActionPerformed(ActionEvent) 
DDMT.core.DataImportPanel.openHeteroFile(File) 
DDMT.core.DataImportPanel.jButton8ActionPerformed(ActionEvent)  
DDMT.core.DataImportPanel.openFile(File) 
DDMT.core.DataImportPanel.jButton15ActionPerformed(ActionEvent) 
DDMT.core.DataImportPanel.jRadioButton1ActionPerformed(ActionEvent)  
DDMT.core.DataImportPanel.buttonGroup1  
...
DDMT.core.DataImportPanel.jButton8 
DDMT.core.DataImportPanel.jButton9 
DDMT.core.DataImportPanel.jLabel1 
... 
DDMT.core.DataImportPanel.jList1 
... 
DDMT.core.DataImportPanel.jPanel1 
... 
DDMT.core.DataImportPanel.jRadioButton1 
...
DDMT.core.DataImportPanel.jScrollPane1 
... 
DDMT.core.DataImportPanel.jTabbedPane1 
DDMT.core.DataImportPanel.DistributionTypes 
DDMT.core.DataImportPanel.DoubleCellRenderer
```

Here is the openHeteroFile which is throwing the Data Import exception

```
private void openHeteroFile(File f)
{
    File file = null;
    try{
        file = f;
        file.createNewFile();
        FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(reader);

        //The vector that holds the number of columns
        attributeNames = new ArrayList<String>();

        //Read in the number of pairs
        String line = bReader.readLine();

        //load the file
        heteroDistributionModel = new DefaultListModel();
        line = bReader.readLine();
        while( line != null )
        {
            //Set up the RegEx matches
            heteroDistM = heteroDistP.matcher(line);
            firstM = firstP.matcher(line);
            firstM.find();
            String output1 = firstM.group()+" (";
            for( int j = 0; j< nodeTypes[0].length; j++)
            {
                if( controlClass.nodes[Integer.parseInt(firstM.group())].getNodeType().equals( nodeTypes[1][j]) )
                {
                    output1 = output1+nodeTypes[0][j]+")";
                }
            }
            String output2 = new String();
            while( heteroDistM.find() )
            {
                attributeNames.add(heteroDistM.group(1));
                output2 = output2 + " "+heteroDistM.group(1);
            }
            heteroDistributionModel.addElement(new String[]{output1, output2});
            line = bReader.readLine();
        }

        for (String attr : attributeNames) 
            System.out.println(attr); //debug


        jList3.setModel(heteroDistributionModel);
        jList3.setCellRenderer(new DoubleCellRenderer());
        bReader.close();
        reader.close();
    }catch(IOException ex)
    {
        controlClass.showError("Data Import: Error: File "+file.getPath()+" is not a valid Heterogeneous data file!");
    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace(); //debug
        controlClass.showError("Data Import: Error: Unknown problem reading file "+file.getPath()+"!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you running in "Debug" mode? If not, the break points will not be hit.

Comment: Yes I have run in the Debug mode (Debug perspective)

Comment: If you run it from the command line, do you set it for debugging and connect to it as "remote Java application"?

Comment: Yes, I set the debugging mode on. And then ran from shell as "java -cp *.jar DDMT.core.Launcher true" where Launcher is another java class in the same project DDMT

Comment: This is still not giving us a SSCCE.  We need to be able to look at your code to see fully where the problem is.   ... and giving us a few DataImportPanel (your Frame?) calls isn't enough for us to identify your problem

Comment: Have added the DataImportPanel.openHeteroFile(File) code. The exception is thrown from this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a little green ladybug right next to the run button that starts the debugger.

I would make sure the proper calls are being made.  Also check your brackets, breaks, and returns to make sure the code is actually being read.  Please post a SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example) so we can view your code to help you out better.

Edit (after OP added some code)

I'm pretty sure your issue is where you file.createNewFile();

Comment: I have added the outline of the code with full project resolution.

Comment: To specify an SSCCE, I would say that I have two java files - Launcher.java and DataImportPanel.java. I call the Launcher class from shell prompt using "java -cp *.jar DDMT.core.Launcher true" which starts the user interface. And DataImportPanel handles one of the panels in this interface. The openHeteroFile(File) method of DataImportPanel is not being able to read the selected File. I want to debug the user event-driven code from the DataImportPanel. But setting normal breakpoints in debug mode or even giving value printouts (System.out.println) is not working.

Comment: This is still not giving us a SSCCE.  We need to be able to look at your code to see fully where the problem is

Comment: The problem has got resolved. Since I have been launching the GUI application remotely using shell command the debugger has not been functioning. Once I ran the debugger using Debug Configurations, the control stopped at the breakpoint. Basically, it was an issue of Run Configuration, that's all! Thanks